# Flash Projectors and file embedding

Tags: flash

Is it possible to embed a number of .doc, .xls and pdfs into a Flash projector?

Answer (score 0):

Embedding in ActionScript3 looks like this:

```
    [Embed(source = "/assets/MyWebCamera/buzzer.mp3", mimeType = "audio/mpeg")]
    public static var Asset_Buzzer:Class;
```

You will have to change the mimeType and presentation logic for those binary files.
At this time there is no built in office file viewer fir flash.